# Grouped bar plot with observations in the x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have this data.frame IMPORTS.

```
description <- c("Agriculture", "Coffee", "Cotton","Potatoes", "Corn")
sept_2020 <- c(825,300,250,150,125)
sept_2019 <- c(720, 280,220,140,80)

IMPORTS <- data.frame(description, sept_2020, sept_2019)
```

I would like a bar like that: [image]

But the legend would have the variables sept_2020 and sept_2019.
The observations would be in the x-Axis. So, in x-axis: two bars for "Coffee", two bars for "Corn" and so on.

It's possible to do that? I appreciate if someone can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The key in `ggplot2` is to reshape data to long and then plot it. You have data in wide format so you can reshape using `pivot_longer()` and what you want is dodged bars that can be set with `position_dodge()` in the data pipleine. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
description <- c("Agriculture", "Coffee", "Cotton","Potatoes", "Corn")
sept_2020 <- c(825,300,250,150,125)
sept_2019 <- c(720, 280,220,140,80)
IMPORTS <- data.frame(description, sept_2020, sept_2019)
#Plot
IMPORTS %>% pivot_longer(-description) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=description,y=value,fill=name))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position = position_dodge(0.9))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        axis.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.text = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        legend.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold'),
        plot.title = element_text(color='black',face='bold',hjust=0.5))+
  ggtitle('My title')
```

Output:

[image]